# how to execute this command (sql command) in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to execute this query in php page.

**the query:**

```
BEGIN
SET @p=0;
UPDATE users SET cityrate = (@p:=@p+1) WHERE cityid=1 ORDER BY power DESC;
END
```

**options (that dont work) that i already tried:**

```
mysql_query(" BEGIN
SET @p=0;
UPDATE users SET cityrate = (@p:=@p+1) WHERE cityid=1 ORDER BY power DESC;
END");
```

and

```
mysql_query("SET @p=0;
UPDATE users SET cityrate = (@p:=@p+1) WHERE cityid=1 ORDER BY power DESC;");
```

Till now  used this query on events but events aren't allowed on some hosts.
so I am going to use this on cronjobs.

Pls help me.

Comment: The `mysql_*()` API does not support multiple statements in one `mysql_query()` call.  First execute `mysql_query("SET @p=0")` then execute the update statement in another `mysql_query()` call

Comment: Can`t you use PDO with transactions...? And beeing a cron job you can process huge data if needed...

Comment: What does this function/procedure accomplish?